Появляется ошибка при запросе SQL: "read ECONNRESET"
Я пишу бота для тг. Когда боту пишет новый пользователь, то появляется ошибка: "Ошибка проверки группы в SQL: read ECONNRESET"
Вот код, который проверяет есть ли новый пользователь в базе данных:
let checkGroup = function (msg, choosenGroup) {
    let chatId = msg.chat.id
    let groupFinded = false
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Ошибка подключения SQL(для проверки группы): " + err.message);
            return;
        }
        connection.execute("SELECT * FROM dailyProphet", function (err, res) {
            connection.release()
            if (err) {
                return console.error("Ошибка проверки группы в SQL: " + err.message)
            }
            res.map(el => {
                if (el.chat_id == chatId) {
                    choosenGroup = el.choosen_group;
                    groupFinded = true
                    return
                }
            })
            if (groupFinded == false) {
                return addId(msg, choosenGroup)
            }
            checkCommands(msg, choosenGroup)
        })
    })
}

Вот функция, которая берет данные из бд:
let sqlConnect = () => {
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error("Ошибка подключения SQL: " + err.message);
        }
        connection.execute("SELECT * FROM dailyProphet", function (err, res) {
            connection.release()
            if (err) {
                console.error("Ошибка извлечения данных из БД: " + err.message)
            } else {
                whoNeedSchedule = []
                res.map(el => {
                    let course = 4 - Number(el.choosen_group[3])
                    listsOfData[course][0].map(groupFirstStr => {
                        if (el.choosen_group == groupFirstStr) {
                            whoNeedSchedule.push(el)
                        }
                    })
                })
                if (firstSqlConnect) {
                    onListener()
                    firstSqlConnect = 0
                    console.log("Подключение к серверу MySQL успешно установлено");
                }

            }
        })

    });
}

